# Close window if opened in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

i know it's possible to display a new location if you open html in a certain browser but I was wondering if it was possible to close the window instead?

This is what I am using at the moment to load up a new window when you open a link with IE

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=staffbook_IE.html"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: because I want to close the window if opened by IE..

Comment: yes, but why? is it because your site doesn't work properly in IE, or because you've got it working on other browsers and want IE to do the same? or just because you want to annoy IE users? or some other reason? (I suspect most of those reasons have a better solution than the one you're trying to do)